# How can I sort fonts of different languages?

Tags: fonts, language-support, unicode, sort

Is it possible to sort fonts of different languages instead of the alphabetical order which is the default sorting order?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Almost all fonts support Unicode, so many languages are included.

I know one indirect GUI method.

You can launch *Character Map* (`gnome-character-map`), then select needed *Script* in the left and then try to select font names:

[image: character map]

---

From terminal you can use fontconfig utilites and some scripting.
For example the command below will list all fonts for Finnish:

```
fc-list :lang=fi
```

see all options in `/usr/share/doc/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html`.

Comment: I want the fonts to be sorted permanently. For instance, when using applications like Inkscape or Libreoffice, I want the fonts to be displayed in the order i want, instead of the alphabetical order.